# TextButton has disappeared?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've seen that the `TextButton` widget appears in tutorials and parts of the official Flutter documentation. But I seem to be unable to use it. As soon as I try to write down its name, it gives me this error: `Undefined name 'TextButton'.` It appears that it can't find the widget, as if it doesn't exist. Why is it?

Comment: Add your code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you're using the latest version of flutter? Try using `FlatButton` instead and if it doesn't give a deprecated warning then you need to update flutter sdk to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

make sure at the top of your code you have imported:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```